# Different display results in Jupyter depending on kernel (new user question)

Tags: python, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I'm new to Jupyter and am having trouble understanding how certain objects are displayed depending on the kernel that I'm using.

Here is my example.

```
#sc.install_pypi_package("ipython") <<- to install ipython when using pyspark kernel
from IPython.display import Image
img = Image(url='http://python.org/images/python-logo.gif')
img
```

When I choose the python3 kernel, I see the image below my cell.

When I choose the pyspark kernel, I see the text:
`<IPython.core.display.Image object>`

I've see online where people say to use:

```
from IPython.display import display
display(img)
```

But this has the exact same result as above.  I know that I'm misunderstanding something, I just don't know what.

Note that I'm doing this on AWS using ERM Notebooks --> JupyterLab.  Spark is running on an EMR cluster.